# L is countable set on a number line, then K=R\L is

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

L is countable set on a number line, then K=R\L is:
a) K has interior point
b) K has exterior point
c) K has isolated point
d) K has boundary point
e) all statements are false
A good approach is to provide counterexamples to all statements. Can somebody give a hint how to deal with problems of such type?

Comment: Aren't the rationals countable?

Answer (score 1):

The following are my favorite examples of countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$:

- The integers.
- The sets $\{{1\over n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $\{{1\over n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}.$
- The rationals.
- All finite sets, especially $\emptyset$ and $\{0\}$. (But be careful - some authors use "countable" to mean "countable *and infinite*.")

There are more complicated ones I like, but usually these serve my day-to-day needs. You should be able to very quickly determine which of your (a)-(d) hold for each of the examples above, and after considering each of these examples you should be able to figure out the answer to your question.

Comment: Can you please provide counterexamples to all answer choices?

Comment: No, I think you should do the work of looking at the examples I've given you and figuring out which one has which properties. This is an exercise which you need to be able to do in order to understand real analysis, topology, or similar.

Comment: (And which you need to be able to do in order to do well on your exams!)

Comment: Can you tell me what is the addition to the set of rational numbers on the interval (2;3)? Is this (-infinity; 2] and [3; +infinity)? or besides previous all irrational numbers on the interval (2;3)?

Comment: What do you mean "the addition to the set of rational numbers on the interval (2, 3)?" If you mean the *complement of* the set of rational numbers in $(2, 3)$, then your latter statement is right: a real number $r$ is **not** in $(2, 3)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $r\le 2$, or $r\ge 3$, or $r$ is irrational. However, if by "addition to" you mean the *complement of the closure of,* then this is different . . .